# Carousel not working normally if carousel inside carousel using bootrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I success to get working if basic bootstrap carousel :

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

But if I insert carousel inside carousel, its not working normally:

```
<div id="carousel-example-genericprimary" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!--indicator-->
   <!--wrapper slide; #carousel-example-generic1, #carousel-example-generic2, #carousel-example-generic3-->
   <!-- Controls with href #carousel-example-genericprimary-->
</div>
```

Anyone know what the reason the bootstrap (3) carousel not working normally?

Comment: I wouldn't have expected it to work nesting carousels inside each other.

Comment: @Will: should you have suggest?

Comment: @Will: have you any suggestion or solution???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821705/bootstrap-4-carousel-not-working/48879620#48879620
visit this page.I think you will get answer from that page!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821705/bootstrap-4-carousel-not-working/48879620#48879620 I think you will get answer from this page.

Answer (score 0):

Carousels simply do not allow nesting. The bootstrap 4 does not either. It is just the way it works. However, you can always add multiple cards in a slide if you need similar construction. Look on W3schools or MDB for more